# Rollup, VueJS, install Vue Portal

Tags: vue.js, rollup

How can I install an external package in `Rollup` in VueJS. I'm trying to install VuePortal, but I need to use `Vue.use(PortalVue)`, but I don't where put it.

I tried with a package called `rollup-plugin-auto-external`, and I put it in:

```
plugins: [
        ...
        autoExternal(),
        ...
    ],
```

Also I put into the `externals`'s object, but nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a rollup plugin to use `PortalVue`.

`Vue.use(PortalVue)` should go in the entry point file, where you setup the root Vue instance (e.g., `main.js`, `index.js`, `app.js`, etc.).

For example:

```js
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue'

Vue.use(PortalVue)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```